# Django Rest Framework Filter ModelViewSet Field Against Multipe Values

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an issue with my DRF API.

I would like to filter a list of issues against a list of ids. Like so:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/api/issues/?id=2,12
```

This returns the entire list of issues

I've also tried

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/issues/?id=2&id=12
```

This returns a list containing only the object with the last supplied id (the object with id 12

I've also tried the following which all return the entire set

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/issues/?id__in=2&id__in=12
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/issues/?id__in=2,12
```

Here's my serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers
...
class IssueSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    '''Serializer for issues'''
    class Meta:
        '''Model filed definitions'''
        model = Issue
        fields = ('id', 'inspection_sheet', 'picture', 'description', 'resolution')
```

And the view

```
from rest_framework import filters
from rest_framework import viewset
...
class IssueSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    '''Views for issues'''
    queryset = Issue.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IssueSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('id',)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to pass a list to the url like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/issues/?id[]=2&id[]=12`?

Comment: I'm trying to filter the api to return all issues with ids in the list. In the example it would be issue 2 and 12.

Comment: Then you can use it as I mentioned it in the above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you will have to create a [Filterset](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ref/filterset.html) using a [BaseInFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ref/filters.html#baseinfilter):

```
class NumberInFilter(BaseInFilter, NumberFilter):
    pass

class IssueFilter(FilterSet):
   id = NumberInFilter(name='id', lookup_expr='in')
   class Meta:
       fields = ['id']
       model = Issue

class IssueSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    '''Views for issues'''
    queryset = Issue.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IssueSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = IssueFilter
```

You should then be able to use :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/issues/?id=2&id=12
```

Comment: I did have to change NumericFilter to NumberFilter to get it to work.