# filterset_fields with DjangoFilterBackend not working

Tags: django, django-filter

My class:

```
class InvoicePeriodViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.AllowAny,
    )
    queryset = models.InvoicePeriod.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.InvoicePeriodSerializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ('days_interval', )
```

it's not working at all. I searched in other stack overflow questions and they didn't help me ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44720041/django-rest-framework-filter-modelviewset-field-against-multipe-values), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589486/django-rest-framework-filters-and-search-not-working-when-def-list-is-added-to), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45296939/django-filter-backend) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374253/django-rest-framework-filter)).

I have 'django-filter' (django-filter==1.0.4) added to my apps, my django version is (Django==1.11.1) and rest (djangorestframework==3.8.2)

I really don't want to add a **filter_class**. I have other view with filterclass and it's working but I don't want to make so many filterclasses. It would be perfect that the **filterset_fields** feature worked. If not I will have to create the filter_class by a function so I won't have to create 30+ of them.

Answer (score 8):

Well, finally I found the problem thanks to [validname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49918252/5334265) answer. He suggested to use "*filter_fields*" I went into [django-filter documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/migration.html?highlight=filter_fields#view-attributes-renamed-867) and found that in new version (1.1.0) *filter_fields* is renamed to *filterset_fields*, so as I was using django-filter 1.0.4 the *filterset_fields* didn't exists.

Comment: THANKYOU - I had the opposite problem - all docs said to use `filterset_fields`, however I'm using an older version and I should have been using `filter_fields`

Answer (score 0):

You are using DjangoFilterBackend in the wrong way, don't declare DjangoFilterBackend in views.py file if you already declared DjangoFilterBackend globally in settings.py

```
filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
```

Use DjangoFilterBackend like this

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
```

Comment: That's what I did. The problem wasn't that. If you read the answer, the problem was the _filter_fields_ and _filterset_fields_ property